# Trying to use serilog-sinks-azureblobstorage in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore, serilog-sinks-azureblobstorage

**Update:** [I have a very simple example here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/tnpnggdmw82538ke300li/Serilog_bug.zip?rlkey=tbpnb1mmzvcrimn3xbn3tr9e5&dl=1). Neither `File` or `AzureBlobStorage` work. In addition, if `AzureBlobStorage` is set, it gets an exception trying to load `Blazor_Logger_bug.styles.css` - which explains why I had pages not rendering when this was enabled.

I've switched to writing my own logger (wrote it up in less time than I spent trying to use Serilog). But wanted to warn others that it appears to not work and causes unrelated problems in your app.

---

I am having all kinds of problems using this (Serilog to a file sink works fine) in a Blazor server app.

If I set up as follows:

```
var _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
    .CreateLogger();
Log.Logger = _logger;
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(Log.Logger);
```

then it logs to the Azure BLOB successfully. But I have the following problem:

1. The application's page displays blank. The page source is _Host.cshtml without the two <component> nodes (which are everything).

If I set as follows:

```
builder.Logging.AddSerilog();
```

then the web page comes up fine. But I have the following problem:

1. Nothing is logged to the Azure BLOB.

If I set it as follows:

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
{
    loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration);
});
```

then the web page comes up fine.

But I have the following two problems:

1. Nothing is logged to the Azure BLOB.
2. The Console & Debug logging have nothing. I assume because this replaces the logging set to that point.

The full relevant code is:

```
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
    builder.Logging.AddJsonConsole();
    builder.Logging.AddDebug();
}
builder.Logging.AddSerilog();
```

And the relevant config is:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.AzureBlobStorage" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning",
        "Override": {
            "LouisHowe": "Information",
            "ThirdPartyServices": "Information",
            "CommonUtilities": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
        {
            "Name": "AzureBlobStorage",
            "Args": {
                "connectionString": "*****secret*****",
                "storageContainerName": "logs",
                "storageFileName": "{yyyy}-{MM}-{dd}.txt"
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "File",
            "Args": {
                "path": "C:/temp/log-.txt",
                "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
                "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter,Serilog.Formatting.Compact",
                "rollingInterval": "Day"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithThreadId", "WithMachineName" ]
},
```

How can I get this working?

---

**Update:** To repeat, I also have the Serilog File sink configured and it works fine.

I added `Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));` For the code:

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
{
    loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration);
});
```

or

```
var _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
    .CreateLogger();
Log.Logger = _logger;
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(Log.Logger);
```

I got the below in the output. No BLOB is created. The web page does not display.

```
2023-10-09T23:06:38.5791924Z Unable to find a method called WithThreadId. Candidate methods are:
Serilog.LoggerConfiguration With(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration, Serilog.Core.ILogEventEnricher)
Serilog.LoggerConfiguration AtLevel(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration, System.Action`1[Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration], Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel, Serilog.Core.LoggingLevelSwitch)
Serilog.LoggerConfiguration FromLogContext(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration)
2023-10-09T23:06:38.5807420Z Unable to find a method called WithMachineName. Candidate methods are:
Serilog.LoggerConfiguration With(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration, Serilog.Core.ILogEventEnricher)
Serilog.LoggerConfiguration AtLevel(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration, System.Action`1[Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration], Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel, Serilog.Core.LoggingLevelSwitch)
Serilog.LoggerConfiguration FromLogContext(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration)
```

If I use `builder.Logging.AddSerilog();` then there are no output messages with the word `Serilog`, no BLOB created, and the web site does come up.

Comment: Does the [SelfLog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics) reveal anything?

Comment: @jamesSampica Thank you (didn't know of that). Gave some info which I added above as I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: Can you verify that `Serilog.Enrichers.Thread` is installed as a package in your blazor project? This package contains the thread id enricher and the corresponding extension method `WithThreadId`

Comment: @jamesSampica It was not. I installed it - same results. So still not working. (And what really bothers me is that Serilog has the ability to stop pages from rendering.)

Comment: Looks like you also need `Serilog.Enrichers.Environment`. Can you verify that one is also installed?

Comment: @jamesSampica I added Serilog.Enrichers.Environment and Serilog.Enrichers.Process along with Serilog.Enrichers.Thread. The `Serilog.LoggerConfiguration` messages are now gone. But remains - writes to file fine. Does not write to BLOB. Web page does not display. thank you

Comment: Are you writing your log statements through an injected `ILogger<T>` or through the `Log` static class?

Comment: I wasn't able to repro this in a new blazor project. Is it possible you could produce an repro example?

Comment: @jamesSampica Could you please give me the sample project you created? I could first run it (hopefully works). And then figure out what's different between the two. thanks - dave My email is "david -at- thielen -dot- com" (my name)

Comment: @jamesSampica Thank you for providing the example. As I posted in the update above - it did not log. And the `AzureBlobStorage` stopped `Blazor_Logger_bug.styles.css` from loading. So there's definitely issues in Serilog. Again, thank you for the help.